# Firebase Storage Quota for bucket exceeded

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I do understand that we have used too much space on our Projekt but as we are still in developing and α testing I want to ask if there is any possibility do delete parts of Storage or reset it completely?

I sadly can't view the data inside the Console and delete it manually because there is just the warning that my the quota exceeded. 
Trying to delete some old stuff directly from the iOS App also fails.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The quota on a free project is calculated daily. This means that if you wait for a day, you'll have some quota again to perform these operations with.